# Directive for finish ng-repeat not being called when using filter

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got this simple directive:

```
myApp.directive('repeatDone', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) {
                var parentScope = element.parent().scope();
                if (scope.$last){
                    parentScope.$last = Math.random();           
                }
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Here's the list:

```
$scope.photos = [
            { filename: "6798453217_72dea2d06e_m.jpg", tags: "all,travel" },
            { filename: "7222046648_5bf70e893a_m.jpg", tags: "all,family" },
            { filename: "7002395006_29fdc85f7a_m.jpg", tags: "all,kids" },
            { filename: "7302459122_19fa1d8223_m.jpg", tags: "all,family" },
        ];

        $scope.filterByTag = function(tag){
            $scope.filters.tags = tag;
        }
```

Here's the repeat:

```
<a title="photos/{{photo.filename}}" ng-repeat="photo in photos | filter:filters" repeat-done>
    <img src="photos/{{photo.filename}}" />
</a>
```

I have ng-clicks that call the filterByTag function which successfully filters the photos array, however, the repeat-done directive is not being called every time the photos array is filtered, only at "certain" times. One example of it not working would be when I try to filter by "all" and then "family", the photos disappear, but the directive does not fire.

I need to apply a jquery plugin when the ng-repeat is done creating the items and, of course, it doesn't work when the directive doesn't either. Maybe I should be doing this differently, so I'm open to suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: I believe ng-repeat will not destroy html elements every time it applies filter and hence this behavior may be there.

Comment: Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks

Comment: It's like an hack,, create a directive on an element that is the parent of ng-repeat, and watch for filter updates. If filter changes apply the jquery plugin with a $timeout of 0 or more.